# Why is comparison query in Bigquery giving me "unrecognized name" error

Tags: google-bigquery

Please help me out, and what the problem is here and how I can fix it. I wanted to compare results, but got an error message. please where did I get it wrong?. I ran a query to know if values of a column in a table are correct. Hence I added three columns to double check. Then ran a query to query the two columns for any inconsistencies. I got an error message instead.

[pics of first query and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZtAQ.jpg)

[pics of second query for comparison and the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSIEN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your column named "**New_Total**" was a temporary column which not save to dataset "**Avocado_data.avocado_prices**".

If you want to compared like that you can use subquery and the code should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        region,
        year,
        Small_Bags,
        Large_Bags,
        XLarge_Bags,
        Total_Bags,
        Small_Bags + Large_Bags + XL_Large_Bags AS New_Total 
    FROM Avocado_data.avocado_prices 
)
WHERE Total_Bags != New_Total
```